# How do I return a subset in jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

By default it's like this:

```
$.fn.ellipsis = function() {
...
return this.each(function(){
  //do some operation on each element here to see if it qualifies

}
}
```

But now I want to return a subset of all, only those qualify in `this.each(function() {})`,

how to modify the code so that it finally returns only those that qualify?

Answer (score 2):

Check out jQuery's filter function: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: How to do the operation and filter at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using [jquery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) if your filtering mechanism is a function.  makes it really easy to pull out just the items in the array that you need.